# WCF workflow service with Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, wcf, workflow-foundation

I have a WCF Service, and I need know it ,is possible consume form an ajax client?

The extension of the workflow files that I intend to consume are of type .xaml

Comment: any more details? XAML is WPF, And you can of-course consume WCF from WPF

Answer (score 1):

WCF Xaml-based WF Services are exposed as SOAP based services, so ajax client can work out, but it would be very difficult to construct the payload. I would recommend to create a thin layer of webapi that can accept json and interact with WCF service.